# How to grep response to figure out how many calls got timed out?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, curl

I have a curl command which is calling one of our service so if my service timesout, it returns JSON response like below:

```
[{"results":{"response":null},"error":{"errorCode":1001,"message":"Service Timeout","status":"FAILURE"}}]
```

Below is my curl command when I run, I will get above response if there is any timeout

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer some token here" "http://localhost:8080/v2/line?&clientid=120";
```

I am running my above curl command in a for loop for x number of times. Now I want to see how many calls got timed out by checking `"message"` in the JSON response? I mean if I made 1 million calls then how many calls got timedout and what was the percentage of timeout?

So I got below one line for loop which calls curl command but I am not sure how to figure out how many calls got timedout and what was the percentage of timedout? Is this possible to do?

```
for ((i=1;i<=1000000;i++)); do   curl --header "Authorization: Bearer some token here" "http://localhost:8080/v2/line?&clientid=120"; done
```

**Update:-**

This is what I see as an output after running the command:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   226  100   226    0     0  12798      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17384
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   226  100   226    0     0   4591      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7290
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   226  100   226    0     0   6318      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8370
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   226  100   226    0     0   5252      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7793
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   226  100   226    0     0   6139      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8071
1
```

Comment: you can simply pipe your output into `|grep -c '"Service Timeout"'` if you are sure this string will only occur in the error case you are interested in. `grep -c` just counts the matching lines.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how my full curl call looks like with this grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `jq` for all JSON related text processing operations. Of course you could manage parsing JSON with `grep` but IMO this is not the way to go.

Quick example assuming the timeout is equal to error code 1001. The returned number is the number of timeouts which has occurred :

```
for ((i=1;i<=1000000;i++)); do
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer some token here" "http://localhost:8080/v2/line?&clientid=120"
done \
| jq '.[].error.errorCode == 1001' | grep -c true
```

Alternatively, if you want to use grep only (this assumes JSON reply is a single line):

```
for ((i=1;i<=1000000;i++)); do
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer some token here" "http://localhost:8080/v2/line?&clientid=120"
done \
| grep -wcoE '"errorCode":1001'
```

Comment: should I paste it in a bash script and then run that script? or I can copy paste this as it is and run it on the shell?

Comment: no difference will work both ways. just make sure to install `jq` before ;)

Comment: Yeah I don't have jq looks like. I don't see apt-get command to install jq? Any idea? I cannot talk to outside world from my production box so wget may not work.

Comment: `apt-get install jq`

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package jq`

Comment: what distro are you using?  the `jq` package exists in debian, it may be called something slightly different in your distro.  try something like `apt-cache search -n jq | grep -v jquery` or `apt-cache search json sed processor`.  the trick is to refine the search terms so you can find `jq` while excluding all the irrelevant matches (e.g. lots of packages mention jquery)

Comment: I am running ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: I ran above two commands and I didn't saw any output coming from those two?

Comment: Any other thoughts? or any other way apart from jq?

Comment: @user1950349 - see my answer update

Comment: At the end it only prints out 1 everytime even when there are more calls that is getting timed out? I just copied exact command as it is in one line and ran it.

Comment: @user1950349 looks `tr` was messing stuff up. i removed it from the answer. try now

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz I still see 1 at the end somehow after removing `tr`? Added an updated in the question. Check it out.